# Is there a "wait" command?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I need to wait for the night to be able to steal something. Is there a "wait" command, kind of the one in Skyrim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not exactly a "wait", but if the town you're in has an inn or a purchasable house, you can use a bed to "sleep" for a certain number of hours.

Bonus: Sleeping will restore you to full health to boot!

Comment: You can also sleep on bedrolls for free. These can be found in and out of towns.